# Public Transportation Webapp in DJANGO : models (many-to-many relationship) for transportation systems and routes

Tags: django, model, many-to-many, schedule, transport

This webapp would allow users to create alerts about controlers in public transportation in a big city. It would include mostly trains and buses.

I'm quite stuck with how to create the model. I've already created the Alert that has a station attribute with a one-to-one relationship, and a line attribute also.
I have two models : a model Stations, and a model Line.

Now each transportation mode (bus/train) has a line, stations and a schedule.Each line has several stations (or bus stops), and each stations receives many lines. I used a many-to-many fields in the Line model, but I don't know how to order the stations, since a bus will go through each of its stations in an orderly fashion, neither how to link that to a schedule. I thought about making another model "Line_Station" with each instance having the attributes Line, Station and Order, but that doesn't seem optimal for routes that have many stations, since a Route would be each instance of Line_Station for the same attribute Line. I'm new at Django and haven't really had the chance to manipulate the database relationships, but I feel like this problem could be solved with a many-to-many relationship.

(Transportations/models.py)

```
class Station(models.Model):
    Station_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Station_adress = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Station_vehicule = models.ForeignKey(Vehicule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Line(models.Model):
    Line_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    Line_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    Line_vehicule = models.ForeignKey(Vehicule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Line_stations = models.ManyToManyField(Station)


class Line_station(models.Model):
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    station = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(60)])
```

Is there a more optimal way to resolve this ? The point is that I would like to create lines in my django admin and from there, add stations and select the order. If I were to think that this app would attract many users, I feel like creating two more models (routes and schedules) might create too many queries.

Here's the Alert model if it is of any interest :

(Alerts/models.py)

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    alert_whistleblower = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alert_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    alert_station = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alert_line = models.ForeignKey(Line, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alert_remarks = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('alerts:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Here's a diagram of the models, but I don't really know how to connect Schedule to route, since the model Route wouldn't be "one route" but many instances (one route would be each instance of the same line attribute, and an order).

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct6Oy.png)

How can I make my model more optimized ?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I've used the relationship Many-to-Many on the model Line, using through = 'routes'.

```
class Line(models.Model):
    Line_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    Line_stations = models.ManyToManyField(Station, through="Route")

class Route(models.Model):
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    station = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm still not sure about this. Should the many-to-many field go to Station ? Should both have one ? I still don't know how to make a model schedule on top of this. Ordering each instance of Route is quite a pain in the ass by the way, since I'd like it to auto-increment for a line instance.